# Pytorch tensor indexing: How to gather rows by tensor containing indices

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I have the tensors:

**ids**: shape (7000,1) containing indices like `[[1],[0],[2],...]`

**x**: shape(7000,**3**,255)

`ids` tensor encodes the index of bold marked dimension of `x` which should be selected.
I want to gather the selected slices in a resulting vector:

**result:** shape (7000,255)

**Background:**

I have some scores (shape = (7000,3)) for each of the 3 elements and want only to select the one with the highest score. Therefore, I used the function

```
ids = torch.argmax(scores,1,True)
```

giving me the maximum ids. I already tried to do it with gather function:

```
result = x.gather(1,ids)
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution you may look for

```
ids = ids.repeat(1, 255).view(-1, 1, 255)
```

An example as below:

```py
x = torch.arange(24).view(4, 3, 2) 
"""
tensor([[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3],
         [ 4,  5]],

        [[ 6,  7],
         [ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15],
         [16, 17]],

        [[18, 19],
         [20, 21],
         [22, 23]]])
"""
ids = torch.randint(0, 3, size=(4, 1))
"""
tensor([[0],
        [2],
        [0],
        [2]])
"""
idx = ids.repeat(1, 2).view(4, 1, 2) 
"""
tensor([[[0, 0]],

        [[2, 2]],

        [[0, 0]],

        [[2, 2]]])
"""

torch.gather(x, 1, idx) 
"""
tensor([[[ 0,  1]],

        [[10, 11]],

        [[12, 13]],

        [[22, 23]]])
"""
```

Comment: Works nice! Thank you very much. I also added another solution I found myself. But I'm not sure which one is faster

Answer (score 2):

using the example of David Ng I found out another way to do it:

```
idx = ids.flatten() + torch.arange(0,4*3,3)

tensor([ 0,  5,  6, 11])



x.view(-1,2)[idx]

tensor([[ 0,  1],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [22, 23]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may provide better memory read pattern in cases where the dimensions are higher.

```
# data
x = torch.arange(60).reshape(3, 4, 5)
# index
y = torch.randint(0, 4, (12,), dtype=torch.int64).reshape(3, 4)
# result
z = x[torch.arange(x.shape[0]).repeat_interleave(x.shape[1]), y.flatten()]
z = z.reshape(x.shape)
```

An example result of the x, y, z will be

```
Tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
     [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

    [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
     [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
     [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
     [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

    [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
     [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
     [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
     [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
tensor([[1, 1, 2, 3],
    [3, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]])
tensor([[[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
     [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

    [[35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
     [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
     [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
     [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]],

    [[45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
     [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
     [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
     [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]])
```