# Is there a function in Pytorch to do a batch span selection?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, vectorization

I have three tensors:

- `tokens` (shape `[N, T]`),
- `start_index` of shape **[N]** and values in range **[0, T)**
- `end_index` of shape **[N]** and values in range **[0, T)**

I want to select spans from the batch of token sequences `tokens` using `start_index` and `end_index`.

Essentially this is what I want:

```
[seq[s:e] for seq, s, e in zip(tokens, start_index, end_index)]
```

Is there a faster Pytorch-way to implement this?

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the slices of each row are of the same length? Otherwise, you would not be able to store them in a single tensor anways, which probably causes performance issues as well. There are also [slightly related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523290/select-mask-different-column-index-in-every-row) ([or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881002/pytorch-tensor-indexing-how-to-gather-rows-by-tensor-containing-indices?rq=1)).